# Node.js connect-multiparty catch Error: maximum file length exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to limit file upload size and inform user about exceeding the limit, but I don't know where I should catch this error.

Limit setting:

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart({
    maxFilesSize : 2 * 1024
});
```

Upload post:

```
app.post('/upload', multipartMiddleware, function (req, res) {
```

Comment: Google `javascript input file size validation`

Comment: Thanks for response, but I need server side solution.

Comment: Connect-multiparty calls `next(error)` internally if there's an error, which means it will be handled by either express's internal errorHandler or the one you added(*app.error(...)*) if you look into the source of the module you will see it's so simple you could implement it yourself and have total control over it.